# while passing string array from eventlistener, it throws an error

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Error :85 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.

code:

```
username.addEventListener('focusout', Exist(existed_username) );
```

can we pass argument like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this.

```
username.addEventListener('focusout', ()=>Exist(existed_username) );
```

Comment: thanks it worked . but why can you provide link which explains this ()=> .

Comment: Because you need to pass a function there. Currently you are calling a function. 
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
this is the syntax. We have to pass a function as the second parameter.
Thats why I passed an arrow function. 
You can do like this also: 
username.addEventListener('focusout', function(){Exist(existed_username)} );
Hope you understand.

Comment: got it thanks    .

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but not like that. You're basically executing the function right away, which should only occur upon firing that event. Instead, you can do:

```js
username.addEventListener('focusout', Exist.bind(username, existed_username));
```